# What kind of resource is available on each type of map in As Far As The Eye?

Tags: as-far-as-the-eye

In As Far As The Eye, at the beginning it seems that all the resources are available on the first map but then each map seems specialized in some type of resources while other are missing.

For instance a Canyon has more rocks to mine and less woods.

[image]

I don't want to halt on a map that does not have the required resources to go further. So what are the typical resources I can find on each type of maps ?